# How can I restart a class added in prefix.pch in my objective c project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pch

I added a extension class into my prefix.pch. I added some private functions to this class. WHen I call this class from some viewController, this is initialized, but when I call again isn't reinitilized.

How could be possible reinitialized this class?

Update: I need do this without close my application.

Comment: clean and build?

Comment: I have update my question adding that I need update this class without close app or rebuild. @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic

Comment: Your question seems rather vague... Can you show your class extension code? Or at least a representative example? (I'm wondering why you don't simply add a "reset" method...)